# How do I edit ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website I am trying to take over that has a small SQL Server database and is written in ASP.NET. Ultimately I would like to change it over to HTML if possible, but I am lost. I am trying to make it so that customer data, when purchases occur export in specific way to csv for quickbooks to be able to read

Answer (score 1):

Well all asp.net sites "crank out" and spit out 100% browser standard HTML.

However, like any rich application development environment, web sites these days involve a server side development system.

In the case of asp.net, that means vb.net, or c# would have been used. As a result, the html source files are of ZERO use here. you will need the Visual Studio project used to create + develop this application with.

In other words, you need Visual Studio, and you need the source code for that project. The published files to the web server WILL NOT suffice here.

So, like the LAMP stack, or any serious web systems (which are FAR FAR FAR more then just HTML), then you need the application system, and source code used to create that application. Anything else is 100% sheer folly.

Your least worry and concern is the HTML. You need the business logic, and the code which represents the cost and time of any application - the HTML is really a side show to this process - especially when using asp.net.

So, you need to get the source code and the Visual Studio project used here.

Was C# used? Or was vb.net used?

you will find in asp.net, that most of the system often uses very little markup.

So, for example, I might drop in this markup into that asp.net page:

```
    <h3>My Hotels</h3>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

But, my code from the project will be say this;

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Description
             FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"

        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End If


End Sub
```

And we now get this:

[image]

so, as noted, you need the source code here, and you need to edit and design this application with Visual Studio.

You also want to determine if the site was built using web forms (a lot if not most older sites were), or MVC was used.